# Set AutoLayout CustomCell TableView for different screen sizes Swift 4 on Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, custom-cell

I can't set the autolayout to my cell for any size screen for all iPhones. I trying make to iPhone SE and iPhone 8 Plus but not works. When I execute my project nothing appears on table.

I did try:
Set constraints.
Check use auto layout options.
Use suggest constraints.
I not sure of the information needed to contextual my question.

[image]

Comment: Do you can explain more like in which situation you are facing problem beside this do you can provide constraint that you provided to your cell.

Answer (score 0):

See a demo here that accomplish the same thing [cellSize](http://www.mediafire.com/file/dczo0nzkzuo2zqq/cellSize.zip)